# Software Engineering UML modeling Tool For Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, uml, diagram

I need UML modeling tool for Ubuntu such as [STARUML](https://sourceforge.net/projects/staruml/). I need to design Sequences, Activity, UseCases for My Projects.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [DIA](http://daksh21ubuntu.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/dia-tool-for-drawing-uml-and-other.html) or [Creately](http://creately.com/Draw-UML-and-Class-Diagrams-Online) (web-based APP).